# Add textView to a ListView as a divider

Tags: android, listview, textview, adapter

I am trying to add a TextView to my list view but when i do it i get a force close. I am trying to display the fist letter in the songname before the song.  songlist is a string arraylist and this is all in a list view.

```
 Collections.sort(songtitle);
              TextView divide = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.song);

              adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);
              int l= 0;
              while(l < adapter.getCount()-1 ){
                  if(songtitle.get(l).charAt(0) == songtitle.get(l+1).charAt(0)){
                      adapter.add(songtitle.get(l));
                     }else{
                      String songname1 = songtitle.get(l);
                      String newString = songname1.substring(0,1);
                      divide.append(newString);// This is where i get the force close  ... I want to display this textView ////

                  }
                 l++;
              }


                setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: share errorLog . also songtitle arrayList .

Answer (score 3):

As stated before, you should try creating your own custom `Adapter`.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

In this there are a few methods, that you need to override in particular `getView()` and `getViewTypeCount()`. The latter returns the number of types of ListItems that can be in your `List` (e.g. song and letter `TextView`).

You should check out [this guide](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) on adding seperators to a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a CustomAdapter with its custom view to do this.

Comment: +1, respect to you sir, but You should provide more info along with this 1 line answer.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this can u explain